# How to resolve undefined nextProps in componentWillReceiveProps event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I've registered the componentWillReceiveProps event in a component. As explained in [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/01/08/A-implies-B-does-not-imply-B-implies-A.html) I listen for nextProps in the in this event during the update phase of the lifecycle.

But logging the value of nextProps returns undefined - `"Chart.js?5478:88 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dashboards' of undefined"`

If I assign the value of `this.props.dashboards` I can see that the data is present. But the values are not up to date. Which is why I listen for `nextProps.dashboards`.

**Question:**

Why does the nextProps parameter in componentWillReceiveProps return undefined?

This is a gist of the Chart.js file where I listen for updates to the dashboards and currentDashboard props:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';    
import Spinning from 'grommet/components/icons/Spinning';
import Heading from 'grommet/components/Heading';
import drawing from '../chartLib/';



 class Chart extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {data: [], loading: true};
    }


    componentWillReceiveProps ({ blockName, subcatName, nextProps }) {

        if(nextProps.dashboards)  //this check for nextProps.dashboards returns: "Chart.js?5478:88 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dashboards' of undefined"
        {
            console.log("The nextprops dashboards values are: " + nextProps);

        }

         this.setState({ loading: true});
         var dashboardsArray = this.props.dashboards;     //this contains the dashboards property value, but the values are one less than the last update.

    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <Spinning />;
        } else {
            if (this.state.data.length === 0) { 
                return (<Heading>Nothing to Show</Heading>);
            } else {
                return (
                    <div className={'why'}>
                        {drawing(this.state.data)[this.props.blockName][this.props.subcatName]}
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }
    }
}


Chart.propTypes = {
  blockName: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  subcatName: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  currentDashboard: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  dashboards : React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
};



const mapStatetoProps = ({ currentDashboard, dashboards }) => ({ currentDashboard, dashboards });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are destructuring nextProps, so you are actually trying to access `nextProps.nextProps`, which is undefined.

```
componentWillReceiveProps ({ blockName, subcatName, dashboards }) {

        if(dashboards)  
        {
            console.log("The nextprops dashboards values are: " + dashboards);

        }

         this.setState({ loading: true});
         var dashboardsArray = this.props.dashboards;     //this contains the dashboards property value, but the values are one less than the last update.

    }
```

For more information about how destructuring works in ES6, you can read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: ah ok so instead I reference the props name from within the array of nextProps. cool